# React - Loading component on every component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react web app has a page component. The page component does the async calls for the child components. Now I have to this on every page

```
export default class Page extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        loading: true
    }
}


componentWillMount = async () => {
    // ... do calls 

    this.setState({
        loading: false
    })
}


render () {
    if (this.state.loading) {
        return <Loading/>
    } else {
        return (
            // Some other components that needs the information from the calls 
        )
    }

}
}
```

Is there a way to have less boilerplate? I was looking at Higher Order Components with ReactJS. I thought maybe a component that would get a function of the calls needed to be made and a component that renders the function.

```
const loader = (calls) => (WrappedComponent) => {
    return class Loader extends React.Component {

        constructor (props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                loading: true
            }
        }

        componentWillMount = () => {
            // execute calls function
        };

        render () {
            return this.state.loading ? <Loading/> : <WrappedComponent {... this.props }/>
        }
    }

};

export default loader;
```

But I haven't figured out a way to pass a calls function into the loader function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do it using a HOC.

Let's say your function is something along the lines of

```
const yourFunction = () => {
  return 'A value';
}
```

Then you can simply pass it to your HOC as a second parameter:

```
const loader = (WrappedComponent, someFunction) => {
    return class Loader extends React.Component {

        constructor (props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                loading: true,
                value: '',
            }
        }

        componentWillMount = () => {
            // execute the function you passed it
            this.setState({value: yourFunction()});
        };

        render () {
            const { loading, value } = this.state;
            return loading ? <Loading/> : <WrappedComponent value={value} />
        }
    }

};
```

Then wrap your component with it:

```
const EnhancedComponent = Loader(WrappedComponent, yourFunction);
```

Alternatively, you can wrap your HOC in another HOC to pass in stuff like that..

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. Didn't think a HOC was so easy.